# Making money by selling data on which language features confuse developers the most

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, business-model

Would it be possible for SO to make money by selling data to major players in the software industry? Specifically, information about which language/platform/framework features give developers the most trouble? E.g. Microsoft for the .NET platform, Google for Android, Apple for iOS, and so on. That could lead to better documentation, life becoming easier for developers, and platforms in general improving?

Would it comply with SO's terms of service if a third party dev made an app that does this?

I hope this question is on-topic for MSO.

Comment: Er, did what exactly?

Comment: What's to sell? It's in the commons. If answers were locked up until sold to a vendor, we'd have another one of *those* Sites-That-Shalt-Not-Be-Named. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Also, doesn't Google already endorse SO for Android questions: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html ?  I know Apple employees that have contributed to the [iphone] and [cocoa] tags, as well.

Answer (score 13):

Official [Stack Overflow support for Microsoft's MSDN](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-results-featured-in-msdn-search/)… FREE.

Official [Stack Overflow support for Google Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html)… FREE.

Official [Stack Overflow support for Canonical's Ubuntu](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/ubuntu-stack-exchange-is-askubuntu-com/)… FREE.

Real conversation with eleven-year-old son: PRICELESS.

There are some things [that money can't buy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cNDSPutas8)…

Comment: Thanks for collecting all these in one page.